# Hide li if no matching attributes on page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hide

Trying to find a way to hide a list item if there are no attributes on the page to match it.

I have a `<li><a href="http://www.somewhere.com" data-filter="name">link</a></li>` on one part of the page and i have `<div id="thisitem" rel="name">stuff here</div>` on another.

If data-filter and rel don't match I want to hide the "<'li'>" with jQuery.

At this point i'm using alert to see if at least some of it is working. Part of it is, but the problem is that it hides all "<'li'>"'s. I would like it to hide only the one that doesn't match.

```
jQuery("#portfolio")
var $filter = jQuery('#filter a').attr('data-filter');
var $item = jQuery('#portfolio-overview article').attr('rel');
    if( $filter != $item)
    {
       jQuery($filter).hide();
    }
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers,
Mike

UPDATE: Here's a fiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/9BsnV/1/.

Comment: how do all the LI's match? what's the data-filter string look like on those anchor elements? they can't all be the same

Comment: Need to see some HTML. A fiddle is a plus too!

Comment: Hi..here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/9BsnV/1/. right now it's set to alert.

Comment: The code does not really match the request. In your fiddle, are you try to filter the articles shown when clicking a hyperlink? I assumed so and here is a fiddle to make that happen: http://jsfiddle.net/9BsnV/3/

Comment: Hi Malk,
I apologize i'm more or less a novice when it comes to jQuery. I'm trying to hide the <li> that does not match any rel on the page when the page loads. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/9BsnV/6/

Comment: Hi Malk! That is so close. This is totally my fault but sometimes the rel has double values like this rel=".wordpress .photography" and in your fiddle it's hiding the rels with the double values. Is there a way to make sure that all values in the rel are targeted? And also exclude data-filter="*" at all times? Great work man!

Comment: I can only get one of the two to show up by modifying this function like this. function cleanVal(v){
   return v.replace(/^\./,'').replace(/\s$/,'').split(" ")[0];
}

Comment: okay got everything except how to exclude a rel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Malk helped with the majority of this. I had some issues that remained though of which I was able to figure out. The two issues where keeping the first li active and the second was dealing with rel's that had multiple values which were not displaying. I took @Malk's code

```
var rels = [];
$("#portfolio article").each(function(){rels.push(cleanVal($(this).attr("rel")))});
$("#filter a").filter(function(){return ($.inArray(cleanVal($(this).data("filter")), rels) == -1);}).parent().hide();

function cleanVal(v){
return v.replace(/^\./,'').replace(/\s$/,'')
}
```

and modified it this way.

```
var rels = [];
jQuery("#portfolio article").each(function({rels.push(cleanVal(jQuery(this).attr("rel")))});
jQuery("#filter a:not(:first)").filter(function(){return (jQuery.inArray(cleanVal(jQuery(this).data("filter")), rels) == -1);}).parent().hide();

function cleanVal(v){
return v.replace(/^\./,'').replace(/\s$/,'').split("")[0];
}
```

Now whenever there is active list item with a data-filter that doesn't match any other rel items on the page it will not be displayed. Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9BsnV/10/. Notice the li named UI with data-filter .UI..it is not showing.

This is helping me out with isotope filtering and pagination getting along.

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#filter a")
  .not("[data-filter=" + $('#portfolio-overview article').attr('rel').replace(/^\./,'').replace(/\s$/,'') + "]")
  .parents("li")
  .hide();
```

Comment: Hi Malk,
I'm getting this error. Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-filter=.photography ]. Any thoughts?

Comment: I took the brackets out and it hides all li's.

Comment: I altered the code to trim leading periods and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted, I'd suggest, perhaps:

```
$('li a').filter(function(){
    return !$('div[data-rel="' + $(this).data('name') + '"]').length;
}).closest('li').hide();
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Comment: Hi David. The rel name is being added with php. So is there a way to get this to work knowing that info?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#filter a').each(function () {//process the links
    var $filter = jQuery(this).data('filter');
    jQuery("#portfolio").find(".item").each(function () {/process the list
        if ($.trim($(this).attr("rel")) == $filter) {// trim that trailing space and compare
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: FYI short version of above:

```
jQuery('#filter a').each(function () {//process the links
    jQuery("#portfolio").find(".item[rel*='"+ jQuery(this).data('filter')+"']").hide();
});
```

EDIT2: Opposite effect:

```
jQuery("#portfolio").find(".item").each(function () {
    var rel = $.trim($(this).attr('rel'));
    jQuery("#filter a").filter(function () {
        return ($(this).data("filter") == rel);
    }).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: Hi Mark,
This makes all the #portfolio items disappear.

Comment: True, they all have a match...at least in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Okay..how could this be made to hide the filter a that doesn't have a match on the page?

Comment: I added the OPPOSITE example as your question is not so very clear.

Comment: Hi Mark...I would like to hide the UI link because it's data-filter does not match any rel's on the page. Hope that clarifies it a bit.